# Switching between editor and console in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I usually use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to send a code selection from the Eclipse (Juno) PyDev editor to the interactive console. But this passes control to the console.

I was wondering if there is any way to automatically (or using a shortcut) return control to the code editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the preferences of Eclipse, go to "PyDev/Editor/Interactive Console" and uncheck "Focus console when an evaluate command is sent from the editor". This will leave the focus in the editor, while evaluating the code in the console.